# Couchbase's view Automated Index Updates setting

Tags: json, performance, caching, curl, couchbase

I'm looking for a way to change Couchbase's view Automated Index Updates setting.

I've followed [this Couchbase documentation](http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-operation-autoupdate.html) and produced the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST http://Administrator:welcome@localhost:8091/settings/viewUpdateDaemon -d 'updateInterval=7000&updateMinChanges=1'
```

But I'm getting back an error:

> {"updateInterval":5000,"updateMinChanges":5000,"replicaUpdateMinChanges":5000}'updateMinChanges'
>   is not recognized as an internal or externa l command, operable
>   program or batch file.

When I try to change only one parameter, for example:

```
curl -X POST http://Administrator:welcome@localhost:8091/settings/viewUpdateDaemon -d 'updateMinChanges=1'
```

It didn't give any error back but settings remained the same (produced in the response):

```
{"updateInterval":5000,"updateMinChanges":5000,"replicaUpdateMinChanges":5000}
```

I also tried to send fields in JSon format with the same outcome - no error but settings did't change.

```
curl -X POST http://Administrator:welcome@localhost:8091/settings/viewUpdateDaemon -d '{"updateInterval":7000,"updateMinChanges":100,"replicaUpdateMinChanges":100}'
```

So my question is: How one can change Couchbase's view settings via curl REST API?
I use [latest Couchbase server v.2.0.1](http://www.couchbase.com/download)

Comment: I have used the following command:


    curl -X POST -v -d 'updateInterval=7000&updateMinChanges=7000&replicaUpdateMinChanges=7000' 'http://Administrator:password@192.168.0.34:8091/settings/viewUpdateDaemon'

with no issue on my Couchbase 2.0.1 cluster.

Not sure what is happening in your environment

Comment: @Tug Grall Thank you. I think its my windows curl utility. I did great HTML form: <FORM method="POST" action="http://Administrator:welcome@localhost:8091/settings/viewUpdateDaemon">
<input type="text" name="updateInterval" value="7000">
<input type="text" name="updateMinChanges" value="1">
<input type="text" name="replicaUpdateMinChanges" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Apply">
</FORM> and it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late to the game, but...

The content of the request is form data.

So you should post it as such.

Content could be (for your case):

updateInterval=7000&updateMinChanges=1